# tabularx and pmatrix alignment issue

Tags: matrices, tabularx

Why are the following entries in the table not vertically aligned? I see that the first column is too low and the second column is too high.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,amsmath,color}

\begin{document}

\begin {centering}
    \huge{\textbf{Homogene Transformationen}} \\[20pt]
\end{centering}


\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}

\hline

    \color{red}{\textbf{Translation}} 

    &

    T = $\begin{pmatrix}
                1 & 0 & d_x \\
                0 & 1 & d_y \\
                0 & 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix} $\\

    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's *very* unfortunate that MathJax forces one to write `\color{red}{text}`, which is utterly wrong in LaTeX and still has no `\textcolor` command.

Comment: @egreg I agree it should be the default (I tried to convince them) but mathjax has had a configuration to use better color for ages http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=latex#color  you could put in a feature request for math,sx to use that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\color` does not take the text to be coloured in an argument, you should use

```
 \textcolor{red}{\textbf{Translation}}
```

not

```
 \color{red}{\textbf{Translation}}
```

As noted in the `color` package documentation `\color` at the start of a table cell can affect the positioning, use of `\textcolor` starts the paragraph before the colour change so avoids that problem.

[image]